# iPhone UI Picker

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, interface-builder

I came across this application, that appeared to have customized the UI Picker.  I thought you were not able to customize certain aspects of the picker.  So maybe this is a custom interface, but it looks too similar to a picker.

Comment: They probably just rebuilt it from scratch.

Comment: I thought that might be the case, looks very similar to Apple's Picker though

Comment: Looking at [Apple's UIPickerView documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html), I don't see any admonishments *against* subclassing it or augmenting functionality of it.

Comment: I agree with BoltClock. This is almost definitely a custom picker and *not* a subclass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created similar picker :

[image]

Using UITableView and Action sheet. I added table view into action sheet(for animation).